# Can I make sure that this element stays on other screens?

Tags: html

```html
<DIV style="position: absolute; top:401px; left:1450px; width:400px; height:25px"><a href="http://www.test.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6U5ufB.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/vo8DDLK.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/p6U5ufB.png'"></a></DIV>
```

I'm making a website right now, and I ran into some problems that I just can't fix.

I have some elements on my website, and they keep moving when I open the website on other screens.

What can I do to make this element stay no matter what size it is? - Same for other elements.

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed`?

Comment: It is just the same as `absolute` in positioning, but `fixed` makes the element stick/fixed to its position, like those navs that sticks in the upper part of the screen when you scroll down

Comment: Didn't work. :/

Comment: It still moved?

Comment: Yeah, it did. The site aren't responsive, if that means anything? - The green buttons should be close to a element, but instead it just moves a lot to right.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using fixed pixel sizes. But different screen sizes have a different amount of pixels. So if you want the location of your object relative to the screen size, you should use percents or viewport-width and viewport-height.

Try something like this: `left: 50vw`

Comment: Hi. Since I want the element to to have a specific position, does this then help?

Comment: Hi. I think you should rethink the concept how you code your website If you work with pixels, it will always only look on your screen how you see it. Your divs should always be positioned with percents or viewport-with and -height or maybe relative to other divs. With this you can easily responsive web sites, that look good on every screen size. I think you should research a little bit and find out more about this topic. There are many tutorials to watch, so you can learn how to code better websites. Good luck! :)